# What’s going on with my cactus

Tags: cactus

[image]My cactus has started to to yellow, it was left in the greenhouse over winter in its normal

Comment: Aye, what a pity. I think it is sunburn. Did it get suddenly very hot and sunny in the greenhouse?

Comment: Not that I was aware, I wandered if it was too cold in the greenhouse maybe?

Comment: If it is caused by cold, it is rot.